# File "/home/v/s/vsdev/web/public_html/index.php" is not in document root of Vhost "/domains/d/e/dev.vacancysoft.com/web/public_html/"

Tags: apache-2.2, cakephp

I've got a dev site running under http://dev.vacancysoft.com/

As you go there you can see the error and I really searched the web for the solution but couldn't find any.

It all started with the UID and GUID in suphp.conf. When I changed the values both to 0 (because the error was previous that the values are to high) the new one appeared and I don't know how to go through.

Any suggestions? (I am a begginer so please describe everything which is more advanced).

Cheers!

### Update

The main site is down too, now the problem is really urgent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the virtual server config. http://dev.vacancysoft.com/ should have:

```
DocumentRoot /domains/d/e/dev.vacancysoft.com/web/public_html/
```

I see that you're on Ubuntu. The conf file should be in /etc/apache2/sites-available/ and probably called dev.vacancysoft.com.conf

**EDIT -- EDIT again -- sorry I'm a bit confused about your setup. Can you confirm that the files for the main site (vacancysoft.com) are in /domains/v/a/vacancysoft.com/web/public_html** If so, then the instructions below should be correct:

You need to set up 2 virtual hosts, 1 for each of the two servers:

Edit `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and make sure it has the following 2 lines:

```
Include /etc/apache2/ports.conf

Include /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
```

Edit `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` and make sure it has the following lines:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80
```

Create `/etc/apache2/sites-available/vacancysoft.com.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName vacancysoft.com
    ServerAlias www.vacancysoft.com

    DocumentRoot /domains/v/a/vacancysoft.com/web/public_html
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /domains/v/a/vacancysoft.com/web/public_html>
            DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/vacancysoft.com-error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/vacancysoft.com-access.log combined
    ServerSignature Off

</VirtualHost>
```

`cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/{,dev.}vacancysoft.com.conf`

Edit `/etc/apache2/sites-available/dev.vacancysoft.com.conf` and:

1. remove the ServerAlias line
2. change all remaining instances of `vacancysoft.com` to `dev.vacancysoft.com`
3. Change both insances of `/domains/v/a/vacancysoft.com/web/public_html` to `/domains/d/e/dev.vacancysoft.com/web/public_html`

`sudo a2ensite vacancysoft.com.conf`

`sudo a2ensite dev.vacancysoft.com.conf`

`sudo apache2ctl restart`

Comment: There is nothing in the sites-available folder..

Comment: Ah ok, you need to set up virtual hosts. Are you using a control panel? Which one? Or are you using the command line?

Comment: I am using a command line.

Comment: See edit in answer. Also want to check that `/home/v/s/vsdev/web/public_html` is the path to the live site, vacancysoft.com -- is that correct?

Comment: Well I think so. You can see the errors saying the path on www.admin.vacancycoft.com (main site)

Comment: Are there any VirtualHost blocks in your apache2.conf file? If so can you post them, and also post suphp.conf

Comment: I finished doing your tutorial, as you go to the site you can see that there is a problem loading page now.

Comment: # Include the virtual host configurations:
Include /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/[^.#]*
 only this is with virtual in apache2.conf

Comment: What happens if you run `sudo apache2ctl start`?

Comment: sudo: apache: command not found

Comment: Did you type out apache2ctl ? -- try `/etc/init.d/apache2 start`

Comment: sorry I made a mistake in the previous one. (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs

Comment: Try `sudo apache2ctl restart`

Comment: do you have skype?

Comment: root@ds7359:/etc/apache2/sites-available# apache2ctl restart
httpd not running, trying to start
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs

Comment: skype is fuscata